# Backup all MySQL databases that a mysql user has access to

Tags: mysql, backup, dump

I need to backup all MySQL databases available to a partiular user and store them
*databasename_date.sql*

Is there any way to use mysqldump to dump all databases instead of telling it each database name it needs to backup?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [AutoMySql](http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/) Backup, this is a small script which backsup everything the user has access to and rotates it over a 5 day period.

Answer (score 2):

You can try for linux

> date=`date -I`; mysqldump -u
>   yourusername -p yourpassword
>   --all-databases > /home/LOGIN/backups/xbackup_$date.sql;
>   gzip
>   /home/LOGIN/backups/xbackup_$date.sql

More detailed explaination is given at

http://www.skyminds.net/2004/05/29/backup-all-your-mysql-databases-with-one-line-of-cron/

Answer (score 0):

You can try `--all-databases` switch